# How to call a JavaScript function declared in a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to have a JavaScript function declared in a PHP file, because I need some PHP instructions to be executed in it. How do I load the PHP file in the file I want to execute the function? How do I then call the function?

Here's an example what I'd like to do:

```
    $a = "text_a";
    $b = "text_b";
    echo 
    '<script>
    mostra.flag=false;
    function mostra(){

    if(mostra.flag==false){
        var ni = document.getElementById("notificaDIV");

        var fumetto = document.createElement("div");
        fumetto.setAttribute("class", "menuNotifica");
        fumetto.setAttribute("id", "dialog");
        fumetto.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Notifiche"));
        fumetto.appendChild(document.createTextNode("'.$a.'"));
        fumetto.appendChild(document.createTextNode("'.$b.'"));

        ni.appendChild(fumetto);
        mostra.flag = !mostra.flag; //flag = false->true
    }

    else if(mostra.flag==true){
        document.getElementById("dialog").remove();
        mostra.flag = !mostra.flag; //flag = true->false
    }

    }</script>';
```

I'd like to move that portion of the code into a separate PHP file and call the JavaScript function `mostra()` in a PHP file. Is this possible or must I use AJAX?

Comment: calling javascript function  in php ??

Comment: I think you want to learn about AJAX.